# Put method not available (or visible in Help)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 Controller (PersonProfessionController) with the following PUT method:

```
[HttpPut]
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
public void Put([FromBody]PersonProfessionModel value)
{
    try
    {
        this.MyProfessionManager.Save(value.ToPersonProfession());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LogManager.Error(ex);
    }
}
```

For some reason it's just not available. It's also not visible in the api Help overview page.

On the other hand, I have a method in my PersonController like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
public void Put([FromBody]PersonModel value)
{
    try
    {
        this.MyPersonManager.Save(value.ToPerson());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LogManager.Error(ex);
    }
}
```

This works just fine.

**Question**

Although the PUT method of the PersonController looks very similar to my PersonProfessionController, other than the obvious differences, the former works while the latter doesn't (not even visible).

Any idea what's going on?

**UPDATE**

The complete PersonProfessionController class per request:

```
public class PersonProfessionController : ApiController
{
    private IPersonProfessionManager PersonProfessionManager { get; set; }
    private ILogManager LogManager { get; set; }

    public PersonProfessionController(
        IPersonProfessionManager PersonProfessionManager,
        ILogManager logManager)
    {
        this.PersonProfessionManager = PersonProfessionManager;
        this.LogManager = logManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string languageCode, Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = this.PersonProfessionManager.Get(languageCode, id);

            if (result == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.LogManager.Error(ex);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    #region Save

    // PUT api/PersonProfession/save/
    [HttpPut]
    [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
    public void Put([FromBody]PersonPersonProfessionModel value)
    {
        try
        {
            this.PersonProfessionManager.Save(value.ToPersonProfession());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.LogManager.Error(ex);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult LoadPersonProfessionsForPersonAndDossier(
        string languageCode,
        Guid dossierId,
        Guid personId
        )
    {
        try
        {
            var contextInformation = new ContextInformation
            {
                LanguageCode = languageCode,
                DossierId = dossierId,
                PersonId = personId
            };

            var result = this.PersonProfessionManager.LoadPersonProfessionsForPersonAndDossier(contextInformation);

            if (result == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.LogManager.Error(ex);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

*I altered the code manually to make it brand neutral, this may cause inconsistencies if I changed something differently.*

And the routing, per request:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Get PersonProfession",
    routeTemplate: "api/personprofession/{languageCode}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "PersonProfession",
        action = "Get",
        languageCode = RouteParameter.Optional,
        id = RouteParameter.Optional
    });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "LoadPersonProfessionsForPersonAndDossier",
    routeTemplate: "api/personprofession/LoadPersonProfessionsForPersonAndDossier/{languageCode}/{dossierId}/{personId}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "PersonProfession",
        action = "LoadPersonProfessionsForPersonAndDossier",
        languageCode = RouteParameter.Optional,
        dossierId = RouteParameter.Optional,
        personId = RouteParameter.Optional
    });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PersonProfession Put",
    routeTemplate: "api/personprofession/save/",
    defaults: new { controller = "PersonProfession", action = "Put" }
);
```

Comment: Do both controllers inherit from ApiController?

Comment: It look good, please can you show us all the code from PersonProfessionController?

Comment: Yes. Other methods are available/visible just fine.

Comment: @MarcoTalento: Updated.

Comment: Everything with the controller looks okay. How do you have the routes set up?

Comment: @JeffSiver: Added as well. The first two work, the save obviously doesn't.

Comment: I really dont unstand why people insists to use MapHttpRoute... Try to use Route attribute its easier and cleaner. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @MarcoTalento: That should be standard, base routing is a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! This doesn't work:

```
[HttpPut]
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
[Route("api/personprofession/save/")]
public void Put([FromBody]PersonProfessionModel value)
```

This DOES work:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/personprofession/save/")]
public void Put([FromBody]PersonProfessionModel value)
```

So apparently you shouldn't add `[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]`.

The *why* behind it baffles me, but here you go.

Comment: AFAIK AcceptVerbs is an older implementation, thus replaced by HttpPut. Technically, using both would be redundant, but may cause internal error nevertheless.